# How do I initialize a chart in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, async-await, chart.js

When I try to initialize a new Chart.js chart in jQuery, I get stymied by the timing of returns. I have tried explicit and implicit promise statements and async/await.  This is my best guess, but it does not work.  Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<script>
    function newChart(){
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
      .then(async function (){
        await ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        chart = new Chart(ctx, initialConfig)
      })
    };

    chart = newChart()
</script>
```

The null in the error message indicates that the initial canvas is not returned in time.  I think the purpose of async/await is to wait for a response, but this does not seem to be the case.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null

Comment: [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is used for promises, you cannot just call it on a DOM element, that's where your error is coming from

Comment: @empiric Thank you for your suggestion. Using an explicit Promise statement did not seem necessary as many tutorials and responses in this forum do not use it. Having said that, when I use it as below, the returned value is a Promise statement. I tried to use Promise.resolve(returned value) but could see no change (still a Promised result).   CODE: function newChart(){
      return new Promise(resolve => {
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")})
      .then(function (){
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        chart = new Chart(ctx, initialConfig)
      })
    };